# Possible to use one of the existing standard Java constraint annotations (`@Size`) on my custom Java type?

Tags: java, validation, constraints, bean-validation

Is it possible to use one of the existing standard Java constraint annotations (`@Size`) on my new Java type (`MyType`)?

I don't want consumers of my framework to have to use non-standard annotations in order to apply a simple size constraint to the new data type.

I'd like to be able to apply `@Size` to fields of type `MyType`, but I get this error by `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor`:

```
SampleDTO.java:3: error: The annotation @Size is disallowed for this data type.
  @Size(max = 100)
  ^
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

So far I have a DTO class which contains 1 field of type `MyType`:

```java
public class SampleDTO {

  @Size(max = 100)
  public MyType fileContent;
}
```

`MyType` basically contains a `byte[]` (which will correspond to file content):

```java
public class MyType {

  private byte[] value;

  //..
}
```

Comment: Well the error is clear, no you cannot use this. As `@Size` will only work (as also mentioned in the `@Size` API documentation) for arrays, `CharSequence`, collections and maps. You can add it to the `value` field and put `@Valid` on the `fileContent` field, this would propagate the validation to the actual object.

Comment: I can see that it cannot be used as-is. I'm wondering could it be used if combined with some custom constraint or other magic like telling bean validator to use a new constraint validator when the type is `MyType` for `@Size`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Hibernate Validator you can create your custom implementation of a `ConstraintValidator` interface for your type:

```java
public class MyClassSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Size, MyType> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Size constraintAnnotation) {
        // ....
    }

    public boolean isValid(MyType value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

and then add a FQCN of this validator to `META-INF/services/jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator` file

```
com.acme.validation.validators.MyClassSizeValidator
```

This will solve the part of actually applying the constraint to your class. As for the `hibernate-validator-annotation-processor` processor ... it "doesn't know" about the constraints that aren't built-in so I'd suspect that it'll still complain about it. But you do not necessarily need the processor.

Comment: Here's a post on this if you'd need more details https://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/#use-standard-constraints-for-non-standard-classes

Comment: I may not need the processor but even if i removed the annotation-processor, I guess hibernate validator will still complain (like the annotation-processor) during actual validation right?

Comment: no, it should pick it up via service loader and work fine, you'd just need to implement the validator interface for your class :)

Comment: Tried this approach but found that the `@Size` annotation has no effect during validation. I specified `@Size(min = 1000)` and `value` inside `MyType` only had 2-3 elements but was not considered invalid .. Doesn't look like `@Size` gets propagated to the field for validation